# C# and the Oracle Number Datatype

Tags: c#, oracle, types

I need to read a value from an Oracle database and the field has been declared as Number(38).  How can I do this in C# since the Decimal type isn't big enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `GetString(ordinal)` on the data reader, and feed the result to `System.Numerics.BigInteger.TryParse()`.

Or perhaps you could leave the value in the `OracleDecimal` datatype, like you received it from ODP.NET.  `OracleDecimal` has functions for almost everything, [including math](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/OracleDecimalStructure.htm#g1307536): `Mulitply`, `Round`, `Exp`, and so on.