# Trying to insert value getting error:not all variables bound

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

i'm trying to insert value in a table using insert command as shown in below code but getting this error "not all variables bound" . i tried a lot but it is obfuscated.The issue is occur at cmd.executenonquery.Any help would be appreciated.

c# code

```
[WebMethod]
 public static void SaveUser(User user)
    {
 String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO par_cinfo(Product_Id,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY,CDATE) VALUES (:Product_Id,:CUSTOMER_NAME,:CITY,:CDATE)", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CUSTOMER_NAME", user.CUSTOMER_NAME);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CITY", user.CITY);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CDATE", user.CDATE);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
                con.Close();
            }
  }
    }

}
public class User
{
    public decimal Product_Id { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public DateTime CDATE { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery on button click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var date = new Date();
            var val = date.getDate() + "-" + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            $("#Label2").text(val);
        });



 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=Button3]").bind("click", function () {
            var user = {};
            user.Product_Id = 1;
            user.CUSTOMER_NAME = $("[id*=TextBox2]").val();
            user.City = $("[id*=TextBox3]").val();
            user.cdate = $("[id*=Label2]").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveUser",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                //data: JSON.stringify({user:user}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
            </script>
```

The table which i created in oracle is as follows simply for entering the data in the table

```
Create table par_cinfo
     (
      Product_Id         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      CUSTOMER_NAME      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      CITY               VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      CDATE              DATE

      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you declare a variable in your SQL command, use `@`, not `:`:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO par_cinfo(Product_Id,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY,CDATE) VALUES (@Product_Id,@CUSTOMER_NAME,@CITY,@CDATE)", con))
```

Second, in your SQL `INSERT` command you are declaring a parameter called `Product_Id` but you never added it to your `cmd.Parameters`. So you need to add:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Product_Id", user.Product_Id);
```

Comment: i used your above mentioned correction but still getting "illegal variable name/number."

Comment: @hari Then you need to check the database column type of your 4 columns you are trying to insert. One of them is probably a wrong type than the variable type you are using in the parameter. For example, check if `Product_Id` in the database is really a column that can accept decimal values.

Comment: values which i am entering is as follows: CDATE :{27-11-2017 00:00:00}  ,CITY :"Palam",CUSTOMER_NAME:"Piya",Product_Id:1

Comment: you need to check the database column types.

Comment: it is saame as i mentioned in quetion . how can i make the entry of date  in database in 27-nov-2017 form instead what it is coming currently 27-11-2017 00:00:00 if it is done than i think issue will resolve any idea how to do.

Comment: `user.CDATE.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");`

Answer (score 1):

Where is the Parameter for Product_Id??

add this in your code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Product_Id", user.Product_Id);
```

Comment: i used it but getting issue "invalid number".

Comment: First Convert Your Product_Id to int, and then pass the parameter. Because your 'product_id' field is "Number" data type while creating table,but you are declaring and passing it as a decimal in your code.

Comment: what is equivalent of 'number' datatype in oracle  in c#

Comment: can you please refer this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391765/c-sharp-and-the-oracle-number-datatype

Answer (score 0):

Provide parameter for `Product_Id`. If it is an identity column then remove the field name form your command its self.

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO par_cinfo(CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY,CDATE) VALUES (@CUSTOMER_NAME,@CITY,@CDATE)", con)
```